# add build tasks to maven pom project

Tags: java, maven, maven-compiler-plugin

An existing maven pom project `<packaging>pom</packaging>` which currently collects and packages resources needs to be extended to validate some of the resources.
In the same project I created a java-source directory `src/main/java` and in there I created a small java class to validate some of the resources. In addition I configured the maven-compiler and exec-maven plugin in the pom.

The java class runs fine in the IDE but it fails when I do `mvn clean install` it fails because it cant find the compiled class file. This is because the compile/test-compile phase is not available for pom-packaged projects.

My questions are:

- Can I modify the compiler plugin to execute (compile) in a different phase than the default compile-phase. (I tried with adding an execution tag but no success)
- Why is the exec-maven plugin executed because this was defined in test phase, which according to the docs is not part of the pom-package.
- Are there other possibilities to run this validation task in the pom?

Modifying the packaging from pom to jar is a political sub-optimal solution.

Comment: Something is inherently wrong here. A `pom` project having Java code to compile? What are you really trying to do here? What is your problem and your end-goal? What's your current project structure? Relevant: [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can configure maven-compiler-plugin to run the compilation in the `package` phase of the pom packaging.

```
<build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
         <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>3.5.1</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>compile</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
         </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
         <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
         <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>1.4.0</version>
         <executions>
            <execution>
               <goals>
                  <goal>java</goal>
               </goals>
               <phase>package</phase>
            </execution>
         </executions>
         <configuration>
            <mainClass>com.example.validate.App</mainClass>
         </configuration>
      </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: This is abuse, literally. `package` phase is not for compiling sources.